# find gridview linkbutton control inside a datalist

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I am developing a web application for Medical shop, I am getting some problem their that i am explaining here. I have one Link button in a gridview and gridview is inside datalist in asp.net
How can I find a gridview linkbutton control inside a datalist?
**Code Here**

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnButton" OnClick="btnButton_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

This is Design file code, please review this and help me, If you have any solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to find gird in datalist as below

```
int index = e.Item.ItemIndex;
GridView gv = (GridView)Datalist1.Items[index].FindControl("grid");
```

Then you have to find that control in gridview

```
int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;    
string title = ((TextBox)gv.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtTitle")).Text;
```

Hope it will help you to get your solution..